# Can you disable file header templating for specific projects?

Tags: xcode, file-templates

Normally, as part of our development process, want every file to have a standard file header comment section.  Here's the default one Xcode creates for reference:

```
//
//  SomeFile.swift
//  MyProject
//
//  Created by Joe Coder (Joe@JoeCoder.com) on 1/1/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 JoeCoder, Inc. All rights reserved.
//
```

For my 'Day Job', we've set a custom version that includes our legal copyright information and other specific details.  However, to my knowledge, this is set at the install-level, not at the project level, meaning even if I'm just spinning up a quick project to test with, or a utility that I'm going to use, all of those details get inserted even though technically they aren't relevant.

Is it possible to configure headers at a project-level to override the one at the installation-level?

Same question for the user info since it has my corporate email which again doesn't always apply.

Comment: Scan through [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcode%5D+copyright+project).

Comment: No, but you can add your own templates and choose them when you create files for the project.